# Short bibliographies entries

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

In bibtex, I am using the `acm` bibliography style which shows some authors with initials of first names, and `et al.` for articles that have more than 3 authors, and the article titles.

What is the correct way to display articles in bibliographies with

- last names only
- of all the authors
- and no titles?

I am also OK with using biblatex if needed (I know that I can do `maxbibnames=99` there to show more than 3 authors).

Comment: Do you also want no titles for `@book` entries? Do you want to see the journal name, publisher, location? What about `@incollection`s: Do you want the `booktitle`, the `editor`? ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The styles of the [`biblatex-chem`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-chem) bundle are all quite compact, because they suppress the `title`s for `@article`s and `@incollection`s etc.

Out of the box they print a given name initial and the family name, but that can easily be changed.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=chem-rsc, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareNameFormat{family}{%
  \usebibmacro{name:family}
    {\namepartfamily}
    {\namepartgiveni}
    {\namepartprefix}
    {\namepartsuffix}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}%
}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family}


\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\autocite{sigfridsson,aksin,worman,geer,pines}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Sigfridsson and Ryde, Journal of Computational Chemistry, 1998, 19, 377–395.]

---

Here is how you can get rid of titles for `@article`, `@inbook`, `@incollection` and `@inproceedings` with `style=ACM-Reference-Format` using a Biber sourcemap

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=ACM-Reference-Format, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \pertype{article}
      \pertype{inbook}
      \pertype{incollection}
      \pertype{inproceedings}
      \step[fieldset=title, null]
      \step[fieldset=subtitle, null]
      \step[fieldset=titleaddon, null]
    }
  }
}


\DeclareNameFormat{family}{%
  \usebibmacro{name:family}
    {\namepartfamily}
    {\namepartgiveni}
    {\namepartprefix}
    {\namepartsuffix}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}%
}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family}


\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\autocite{sigfridsson,aksin,worman,geer,pines}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Sigfridsson and Ryde. 1998. Journal of Computational Chemistry, 19, 4, 377–395. doi: 10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P.]

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to maintain the `acm` format of `journal,
4 (1991), 2374`. I can see that the code you had there can work for acm to suppress the given initials, I am only missing a way to remove the titles from that format.

Comment: @Tohiko The approach for the names would indeed also work for `style=ACM-Reference-Format`, but getting rid of the titles correctly would be harder. Incidentally, with `style=ACM-Reference-Format` the year is at the beginning of the entry and not after the volume " J. Organomet. Chem., 691, 13, 3027–3036.". The methods here use `biblatex` and can not be used with `acm.bst`.

Comment: Thanks! I was trying out different styles and I noticed that `apa` does not work with the commands to hide first names. Any idea why?

Comment: @Tohiko `biblatex-apa` uses differently named (and more complex) name formats in order to satisfy APA requirements. If you are really interested you can ask a new question.

Comment: Thanks @moewe. I looked through the source code and it seems if I just do `\DeclareNameAlias{apaauthor}{family}` everything works again.

Comment: @Tohiko Yes-ish. `apaauthor` does a few more things than just calling `\usebibmacro{name:<format>}`, and you will lose these extras if you say `\DeclareNameAlias{apaauthor}{family}`. (This may or may not be an issue for you. But you are already giving up APA compliance by forcing only family names, so it probably does not matter.)